# Ошибки при отправке формы

Tags: php, yii2

Везде на всех формах выпадает ошибка:

> 400 Bad Request

Вот `csrf`:

```
d0ee39aee894ffc9b6d42d4f87debe40e8eda9554fcc6b86b85f370261bd0b1da:2:{i:0;s:5:\"_csrf\";i:1;s:32:\"GIbpFnsIsgItxlnjiMy5p8oBr5M1wD0K\";}
```

Вот что говорит дебагер:

```
8   07:41:51.213    trace   yii\base\Controller::runAction  Route to run: image/create
9   07:41:51.223    error   yii\web\HttpException:400   exception 'yii\web\BadRequestHttpException' with message 'Не удалось проверить переданные данные.' in C:\OpenServer\domains\film.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php:110
Stack trace:
#0 C:\OpenServer\domains\film.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(152): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#1 C:\OpenServer\domains\film.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(454): yii\base\Controller->runAction('create', Array)
#2 C:\OpenServer\domains\film.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(84): yii\base\Module->runAction('image/create', Array)
#3 C:\OpenServer\domains\film.lc\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#4 C:\OpenServer\domains\film.lc\backend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#5 {main}
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть дело или как протестить ошибку?

Comment: случайно не ajax?

Comment: оказалось все проще я использую adminLTE виджет и там одну переменную переименовал и получил кучу проблем (видимо она как то с токеном связана была)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам стоит отключить проверку csrf. Например, так:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = ($action->id !== "<action>"); 
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: И подвергнуть себя опасности ? Зачем.